# How can I assign attributes to form elements in forms.py without using class Meta?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a django form setup like so:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=400)

    class Meta:
        fields = ['full_name', 'phone', 'email', 'message']

        widgets = {
        'full_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'sizefull s-text7 p-l-22 p-r-22', 'placeholder': 'Full Name'}),
        'phone': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'sizefull s-text7 p-l-22 p-r-22', 'placeholder': 'Phone Number'}),
        'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'sizefull s-text7 p-l-22 p-r-22', 'placeholder': 'E-Mail Address'}),
        'message': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'dis-block s-text7 size20 bo4 p-l-22 p-r-22 p-t-13 m-b-20', 'placeholder': 'Message'}),
        }
```

Which works fine. However, I recently learned that `class Meta` can only be used with ModelForms.

I need to assign attributes like the above in my form, in forms.py. I understand it is bad practice to mix business and presentation logic, but I am dealing with a complicated paid web template at the moment, and methods to apply attributes using template tags have not worked so far. Given I am on a deadline, I am postponing assigning attributes that way as a v2 feature.

My question is, if class Meta can only be used with forms that have a corresponding model, how can I assign attributes to form widgets in forms that do not correspond to a model and thus cannot use class Meta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inline widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances).

An example used is as follows:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}))
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '40'}))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.